# How do I calculate trading volume of a particular contract?

Tags: web3js

Let's take [Saturna](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44) as an example.

I want to know what was trading volume in 1 minute time buckets.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, all I need to do is observe [`Transfer` event](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44#events), e.g.

```js
web3.eth.subscribe(
  'logs',
  {
    address: '0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44',
    topics: [
      '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
    ],
  },
  (error, data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
);
```

This will give me information such as:

```js
{
  address: '0x1e446CbEa52BAdeB614FBe4Ab7610F737995fB44',
  topics: [
    '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
    '0x0000000000000000000000002a621eb59522a895a2bc0e5b6c9341adf392892a',
    '0x000000000000000000000000ad7db2aea6e8904347be097f920174469a64774e'
  ],
  data: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054df3de59546157e',
  blockNumber: 7506151,
  transactionHash: '0x65ccabbed15b99ac10e4677141c1718dcc4083cba52786e4853119b45a0e2934',
  transactionIndex: 155,
  blockHash: '0xfab95d76941743259b6f4dd0019d31d078c665dbf54b7d6f419721b76b76278a',
  logIndex: 180,
  removed: false,
  id: 'log_f1c7e670'
}
```

which, when decoded, will tell me the amount of `Saturna` coins transferred:

```js
{
  name: 'Transfer',
  values: {
    from: '0x2a621Eb59522a895A2BC0E5b6c9341aDf392892a',
    to: '0xAD7DB2Aea6E8904347BE097f920174469a64774e',
    value: '6115674875253626238'
  }
}
```

All I need to calculate volume from here is just to add `volume` to time buckets.